# WCF IErrorHandler.ProvideFault() behavior

Tags: wcf, error-handling, ierrorhandler

My service methods are marked with `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` and i have a custom `IErrorHandler` implementation attached to the service. When an incoming request has no permissions to execute the method `System.Security.SecurityException` is thrown. `IErrorHandler.ProvideFault()` is then triggered and i want to provide a special fault. But `error` parameter is not original exception, it's untyped `FaultException`. Moreover, `error.InnerException` is null despite i have the following setting in the config:

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

Why? How can i achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/371181/wcf-ierrorhandler-logging-securityexceptions) `SecurityException` is kind of "special" for WCF:

> SecurityException is related to CAS
>   (Code Access Security), and it is a
>   fatal exception. Since this exception
>   is not related to any service model
>   exceptions, it cannot be handled by
>   IErrorHandler.

So i ended up by creating additional class which methods (called from the methods of the class implementing the service interface) are marked with `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` and a handler function with try/catch.